# How can I show a single instance of a div using jquery? (AJAX, jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an array of forms that has a success message on each. I want to show a success message on the form that is clicked only. However, the success message on all forms are showing whenever I click on a single form. Forgive me for my question as I am a beginner in javascript and jquery. How can I achieve this? Here is my html code...

```
<c:forEach items="${inventories}" var="inventory" varStatus="varStatus">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3" style="padding: 2%;">
        <div class="card">
            <img class="card-img-top"
                src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/image?prodId=${inventory.getProduct().getProductId()}"
                alt="Card image cap"
                style="height: 200px; width: 100% px; display: block; margin: auto;">
            <form:form id="add_to_cart_form" action="addToCart" method="POST"
                modelAttribute="cartProduct">
                <form:input type="hidden" path="user.email"
                    value="${user.getEmail()}" />
                <form:input type="hidden" path="product.productId"
                    value="${inventory.getProduct().getProductId()}" />
                <div class="card-block" style="overflow: hidden; padding: 2%">
                    <h5 style="white-space: nowrap">
                        <a href="#" class="text-primary card-title">${inventory.getProduct().getName()}</a>
                    </h5>
                    <p class="card-text text-danger">&#8369;
                        ${inventory.getProduct().getPrice()}</p>
                    <p class="text-success">In stock</p>
                    <p>
                        <div class="success-message" style="display: none;"><span class="text-success add-to-cart"><strong>Added
                                to cart!</strong></span></div>
                    </p>
                    <form:button class="btn btn-block btn-warning">Add to cart</form:button>
                </div>
            </form:form>
        </div>
    </div>
</c:forEach>
```

And here is my AJAX code...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var form = $("form");
    var url = form.attr("action");
    var formMethod = form.attr("method");

    form.submit(function(event) {

        event.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({

            url : url,
            data : $(this).serialize(),
            type : "POST",
            success : function(cartProduct) {
                $('.success-message').show();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try storing reference of form submitted in variable and then find the success-message in the form that was clicked and show it.

Reference code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var form = $("form");
  var url = form.attr("action");
  var formMethod = form.attr("method");
  form.submit(function(event) {
    var that = this;   //store reference of form submitted in variable
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      type: "POST",
      success: function(cartProduct) {
        $(that).find('.success-message').show(); //find the success-message in the form that was clicked and show it
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I don't understand why $(this).find('.success-message').show() is not working. Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's `.find()` method to isolate the instance of `success-message` which lies within the submitted form:

Replace

```
$('.success-message').show();
```

with

```
$(this).find('.success-message').show();
```

In that context, `this` should represent the submitted form.

See https://api.jquery.com/find/ for a more detailed explanation of how the `.find()` method works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find success message of current form which is submitted.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    // for each form
     $("form").each(function() {
        // current form which might be submitted
        var _this = this;
        _this.on('submit', function(event){
         // on current form submit
         event.preventDefault();
         //send ajax 
         $.ajax({
            url : form.attr("action"),
            data : $(this).serialize(),
            type : form.attr("method"),
            success : function(cartProduct) {
              //on success get success message of this submitted form   
             _this.find('.success-message').show();
            }
         });
       });
    }); 
   });
```

Comment: Your code will show all the `.success-message` elements in the all the forms. OP asked to show the one only is the form that is submitted.

Comment: I miss read multi form but before i could update it for each form it was vote down. I hope the updated answer will find only current form